# Joi validation multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, joi

I have the following schema:

```
var testSchema = Joi.object().keys({
    a: Joi.string(), 
    b: Joi.string(), 
    c: Joi.string().when('a', {'is': 'avalue', then: Joi.string().required()})
});
```

but I would like to add a condition on `c` field definition so that it is required when:

`a == 'avalue' AND b=='bvalue'`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can concatenate two `when` rules:

```
var schema = {
    a: Joi.string(),
    b: Joi.string(),
    c: Joi.string().when('a', { is: 'avalue', then: Joi.string().required() }).concat(Joi.string().when('b', { is: 'bvalue', then: Joi.string().required() }))
};
```

Comment: Please what if I want to group values. like say when takes one of a collection of values and set the validation rule?

Comment: I want the same. Need to check if the key has a value in an array.

Answer (score 29):

The answer by Gergo Erdosi didn't work with Joi `14.3.0`, this resulted in an `OR` condition:

`a === 'avalue' || b === 'bvalue'`

The following worked for me:

```
var schema = {
  a: Joi.string(),
  b: Joi.string(),
  c: Joi.string().when(
    'a', {
      is: 'avalue',
      then: Joi.when(
        'b', {
          is: 'bvalue',
          then: Joi.string().required()
        }
      )
    }
  )
};
```

This results in `a === 'avalue' && b === 'bvalue'`

Comment: yes, I think this is also a better syntax

Answer (score 0):

This search result popped up when I did a search, but the solution I found in the documentation is not here:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
a: Joi.number().required(),
b: Joi.number()
    .when('a', {
        switch: [
            { is: 0, then: Joi.valid(1) },
            { is: 1, then: Joi.valid(2) },
            { is: 2, then: Joi.valid(3) }
        ],
        otherwise: Joi.valid(4)
    })
```

});

It was found here:
[Joi.dev documentation](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.12.0#anywhencondition-options)